# how do I exlude term in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I am having urls in this format stored in mongodb

```
Source:
index.php?name=xxxxxxxxxxxxxabcxxxxxxxx&id=15&success=1
index.php?name=xxxxxxxdefxxxxxxxxxxxx&id=18&success=0
```

where xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is some string

I want to write a query to find all sources where name should not contain "abc" as a substring
So I wrote the query

```
db.coll.find({source:/(?!name=abc)/})
```

but this query is not working..please guide me what will be the correct query

Answer (score 3):

```
db.coll.find({source: {$not: /[?&]name=.*abc.*(&|$)/}})
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-Metaoperator%3A%24not

Answer (score 0):

regex w/ `$nin` (not in). Don't think that is supported as a single query yet...

try looking at

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24nin

http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-322

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/6c7dc2b0f8831fac6621f125889d873241588b02